# What is a Gaussian Lobe concerning BRDF and NDF?

Tags: mathematics, brdf, ndf

I was reading a paper about voxel cone tracing and came across this term. So, what is a Gaussian Lobe or a Lobe in general?

I am asking in the context of Computer Graphics, BRDF and NDF.

Answer (score 2):

In a BRDF or NDF this most likely refers to a [spherical Gaussian](https://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2016/10/09/sg-series-part-2-spherical-gaussians-101/) distribution, also known as a [von Mises–Fisher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution).

It's similar to the usual Gaussian, but using the dot product between two unit vectors as a measure of distance to the mean:

$$ p(\hat v) = a \exp(\lambda(\hat \mu \cdot \hat v))$$

where $a$ is a normalization factor, $\lambda$ is a number controlling the width of the lobe (roughly corresponds to $1/2\sigma^2$ in the usual Gaussian), $\hat \mu$ is the unit direction vector for the mean of the lobe, and $\hat v$ is the unit direction vector at which we're evaluating the lobe.

(You'll also sometimes see it defined with $\lambda(\hat \mu \cdot \hat v - 1)$ in the exponent, but the $-1$ term can be pulled out and rolled into the normalization factor.)

Answer (score 1):

Having a gaussian lobe usually means that your ndf is one or a weighted sum of gaussian distributions. Instead of your ndf, you can define your brdf in the same way.

A [gaussian distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is a function of the form $$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

It has a hat shape common to many ndfs; this is good because it mimicks how normals align in most real world materials